# How to calculate the checksum of this serial data?

Tags: checksum, serial-communication

I am communicating with a device via RS232 serial

this is sample data view

20 02 80 03 64 01 C7 00 B1
20 02 80 03 32 01 05 00 BD
20 02 80 03 32 01 C3 00 7B
20 02 81 07 32 01 C3 CD CC 0C 3F 00 64

checksum byte B1,BD,7B and 64

i need to know how to create checksum  byte

Comment: RS-232 does not specify a checksum algorithm. It doesn't even specify how many bits there are in a byte.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.